# Is there a way to add a new element to a mesh in the action editor?

Tags: modeling, animation

I'm making a few animations for a character in a racing game, run, walk, die and also a win animation in the win animation I want to add a medal around the characters neck, is there a way to do this in the action editor without making a new mesh with the medal in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an intermediate bone, which deforms the medal. On the first frame of the winning animation it will simply have a scale keyframe at `(1, 1, 1)`. On all other actions you keyframe it to a scale of `(0, 0, 0)` effectively hiding it.

Otherwise create a separate object, which the game engine can show/hide.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Do you know if Unity has the option to hide objects? and i'll try the scale suggestion out!

Comment: In unity, when the character wins, [set the object as active](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html).